# CRA + WebPack(react-scripts): Configure relative path for images other than PUBLIC_URL

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-scripts, cra

I've below directory structure for my react app.

```
src
   assets
          dummy.svg
   scss
          dummy.scss
   js
          dummy.js
```

Below is the standard build format generated in CRA.

```
build
     static
           js
                 hashed-js.js
           css
                 hashed-css.css
           media
                 hashed-image.svg
```

I've specified a svg in my scss as `background-image:  url("../assets/dummy.svg")`

If PUBLIC_URL is specified, CSS generated will have image path relative to PUBLIC_URL like

`background-image: url(PUBLIC_URL/static/media/hashed-image.svg)`

Is there a way or does react-scripts/webpack provides some configuration to have some other variable injected rather than PUBLIC_URL?

Something like `background-image: url(REACT_SOME_OTHER_VARIABLE/static/media/hashed-image.svg)`